# read from class defined by variable

Tags: java

I have Java-related question:

I want to know is there a way to create path to class (in program) by using a variable(s).
Im making a program that will download pictures from certain sites and show them to a user. However, different sites have different forms, that's why I have to define a series of functions specific to each. They cannot be put in the same class because functions that preform same job (just for another site) would have to have same names. I'm trying to make adding support for another site later as simple as possible.

Anyway, the question is, could I call a function in program using a variable to determine its location.

For example: `code.picturesite.functionINeed();`

`code` is the package containing all of the coding, and `picturesite` is not a class but rather a variable containing the name of the desired class - that way I can only change value of the variable to call a different function (or the same function in a different class).

I don't really expect that to be possible (this was more for you to understand the nature of the problem), but is there another way to do what I'm trying to achieve here?

Comment: You can do it with reflection, though such code tends to be brittle, verbose, and hard-to-maintain. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. It's called *reflection*.

Given a String containing the class name, you can get an instance like this:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.foo.SomeClass");
Object o = c.newInstance(); // assuming there's a default constructor
```

If there isn't a default constructor, you can get a reference to one via `c.getConstructor(param1.getClass(), param2.getClass(), etc)`

Given a String containing the method name and an instance, you can invoke that method like this:

```
Method m = o.getClass().getMethod("someMethod", param1.getClass(), param2.getClass(), etc);
Object result = m.invoke(o, param1, param2, etc);
```

Comment: I hadn't had enough reputation before! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not immediately seeing anything in your question that couldn't be solved by, instead of having a variable containing a class name, having a variable containing an instance of that class -- to call a function on the class, you would have to know it implements that function, so you could put the function in an interface.

```
interface SiteThatCanFoo {
    void foo();
}
```

And

```
class SiteA extends Site implements SiteThatCanFoo {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("Foo");
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Site currentSite = getCurrentSite(); // or getSiteObjectForName(siteName), or similar
if (SiteThatCanFoo.isAssignableFrom(currentSite.class)) {
    ((SiteThatCanFoo)currentSite).foo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to do something like this (check `ImageDownloader.getImageFrom` method)

```
class SiteADownloader {
    public static Image getImage(URI uri) {
        System.out.println("invoking SiteADownloader on "+uri);
        Image i = null;
        // logic for dowlnoading image from siteA
        return i;
    }
}

class SiteBDownloader {
    public static Image getImage(URI uri) {
        System.out.println("invoking SiteBDownloader on "+uri);
        Image i = null;
        // logic for dowlnoading image from siteB
        return i;
    }
}

// MAIN CLASS
class ImageDownloader {
    public static Image getImageFrom(String serverName, URI uri) {
        Image i = null;
        try {
            // load class
            Class<?> c = Class.forName(serverName + "Downloader");
            // find method to dowload img
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getImage", URI.class);
            // invoke method and store result (method should be invoked on
            // object, in case of static methods they are invoked on class
            // object stored earlier in c reference
            i = (Image) m.invoke(c, uri);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException
                | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                | InvocationTargetException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return i;
    }

    // time for test
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Image img = ImageDownloader.getImageFrom("SiteB", new URI(
                    "adress"));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```